# Stringify array with Objects

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, requirejs, local-storage

My problem is, that I can't access the methods of an object, after using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

I have something like the following:

main.js

```
    var items = [];

    define(['item'], function (item) {

    var main = function () {

    $(document).ready(function) {

    $("#anyButton").on("click", function() {
    items.push(new item());
    items[0].myMethod();    //items[0].myMethod() works fine here.
          });
        });
      }();
    });
```

item.js

```
    var item = function () {
        var construnctor,
            that = {};

        constructor = function () {
            return that;
        };

        that.myMethod= function () {
        };

      return constructor.apply(null, arguments);
    };
    return itemModule;
```

Now I want to stringify the items Array in main.js and store it to localStorage:

main.js

```
window.localStorage.setItem("myKey", JSON.stringify(items));
```

And then parse it back:

```
var parsedArray = [];
parsedArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("myKey"));
```

Now the problem is, that I don't have access to `myMethod` in item.js
The following fails:

```
parsedArray[0].myMethod();
```

produces:

> parsedArray[0].myMethod is not a function.

Where is the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can't serialize functions into JSON - there is no such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringify will only convert value type property, array and objects.

Functions will be omited.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know functions can't be stringified. There is no proper way for me to do this without stringify. What do you think about http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/